# Make select options larger in q-select quasar

Tags: javascript, select, font-size, quasar-framework

I'm using q-select to display the months and the font size is quite small so I want to make the options larger. I tried changing the font-size in css but it didn't work.

My select atm

```
          <q-select
            ref="month"
            input-style="zoom: 1.2; text-align: right;"
            rounded outlined
            clearable
            class="text-h4" 
            v-model="oMonth" 
            :options="oMonths"
          />
```

What the output looks like
[months selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydlgC.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<q-select>` attributes you need to affect the appearance of the popup menu and its option items are `popup-content-class` and/or `popup-content-style`. (You can also use the `option` slot if you need more control over the content of each item.)

Something along these lines would work, for h6-sized text:

```html
          <q-select
            ref="month"
            input-style="zoom: 1.2; text-align: right;"
            rounded outlined
            clearable
            class="text-h4" 
            popup-content-class="text-h6"
            v-model="oMonth" 
            :options="oMonths"
          />
```